# On google-fit api how do I write cycled Kilometers?

Tags: android, google-fit

I am writing a cycling app that will be connected with google fit. At the end of a workout I calculate expended calories and cycled Kilometers through my own algorithms and then report them to google fit. Calories was pretty easy but I haven't found a way to write the Kilometers. The idea would be to make a single report with a number of Kilometers(probably around 10 on a regular workout), is there a way to write that?

This is the code I use for Calories

```
        // Set a start and end time for our data, using a start time of 1 hour before this moment.
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date now = new Date();
    cal.setTime(now);
    long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -1);
    long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

    // Create a data source
    DataSource dataSource = new DataSource.Builder()
            .setAppPackageName(mView)
            .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_CALORIES_EXPENDED)
            .setStreamName("Cyclecast workout")
            .setType(DataSource.TYPE_RAW)
            .build();

    // Create a data set
    int caloriesExpended = workout.getCalories();
    DataSet dataSet = DataSet.create(dataSource);
    // For each data point, specify a start time, end time, and the data value -- in this case,
    // the number of new steps.
    DataPoint dataPoint = dataSet.createDataPoint()
            .setTimeInterval(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    dataPoint.getValue(Field.FIELD_CALORIES).setFloat((float)caloriesExpended);
    dataSet.add(dataPoint);

    new AwaitResultAsyncTask().execute(Fitness.HistoryApi.insertData(client, dataSet));
```

The idea would be to find something similar but for Cycled Kilometers.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: AFAIK, you have to use `com.google.distance.delta` to access the data type which is the distance covered and the [format for the distance is meters](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/data-types#data_types_for_instantaneous_readings).

Comment: I tried but it adds tthat distance to the general "distance walked" activity, I need it to be related to the specific activity I created, or at least to biking.stationary